# C++ loop fusion does not seem to happen

Tags: c++, loops, optimization

Consider two functions, func_a, func_b, which produce equivalent results:

```
int func_a(int const* const arr)
{
    int sum1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
        sum1 += arr[i];

    int sum2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
        sum2 += arr[i];

    return sum1 + sum2;
}

int func_b(int const* const arr)
{
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
    {
        sum1 += arr[i];
        sum2 += arr[i];
    }
    return sum1 + sum2;
}
```

And look at their generated assembly (g++ 13.2 std=c++20 -Ofast):

```
func_a(int const*):
        lea     rdx, [rdi+800]
        mov     rax, rdi
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
.L2:
        movdqu  xmm3, XMMWORD PTR [rax]
        add     rax, 16
        paddd   xmm0, xmm3
        cmp     rax, rdx
        jne     .L2
        movdqa  xmm1, xmm0
        psrldq  xmm1, 8
        paddd   xmm0, xmm1
        movdqa  xmm1, xmm0
        psrldq  xmm1, 4
        paddd   xmm0, xmm1
        movdqa  xmm1, xmm0
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
.L3:
        movdqu  xmm4, XMMWORD PTR [rdi]
        add     rdi, 16
        paddd   xmm0, xmm4
        cmp     rdi, rdx
        jne     .L3
        movdqa  xmm2, xmm0
        psrldq  xmm2, 8
        paddd   xmm0, xmm2
        movdqa  xmm2, xmm0
        psrldq  xmm2, 4
        paddd   xmm0, xmm2
        paddd   xmm0, xmm1
        movd    eax, xmm0
        ret

func_b(int const*):
        lea     rax, [rdi+800]
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
.L8:
        movdqu  xmm2, XMMWORD PTR [rdi]
        add     rdi, 16
        paddd   xmm0, xmm2
        cmp     rax, rdi
        jne     .L8
        movdqa  xmm1, xmm0
        psrldq  xmm1, 8
        paddd   xmm0, xmm1
        movdqa  xmm1, xmm0
        psrldq  xmm1, 4
        paddd   xmm0, xmm1
        movd    eax, xmm0
        add     eax, eax
        ret
```

Q1: Why are the two loops in func_a not fused?

For reference, the manually-fused func_b shows what I hoped the optimized version of func_a would be.

Comment: GCC doesn't implement loop fusion.

Comment: In clang++, there are no loops at all in any of the functions :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo but if you replace the constant trip count by a dynamic one clang also does not fuse the loops as it seems.

Comment: @chrysante True that!

Comment: Is there any guarantee that it is beneficial to fuse the loops?  Depending on the loop count, it might be easier on the cache to leave them as they are.

Comment: In this case it's the same value being read by both loops, so I think it would be an advantage here. -- I'm not that experienced in reading (let alone coding) SIMD code, but I'm surprised by the amount of logic needed _after_ the loop to produce the result.

Comment: ICC does fuse them at O3, but not O2

Comment: @500-InternalServerError it's slightly longer than necessary (Clang shows how to do it with `pshufd` instead of `movdqa + psrldq`) but overall doesn't look like that much to me

Comment: Note that loop fusion can be detrimental to performance in some cases (not in this trivial case where it can be easily done manually anyway). Loop fusion makes codes harder to vectorize, increases the register pressure and can cause cache trashing regarding the cache associativity (only known with `-march=...`) and the number of arrays used in the loop. In fact, AFAIK, GCC implements loop fission because of that. It would cause [conflits with loop fusion](https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/gcc/2015-April/217294.html). Vectorization and caching matters more than not reloading data from the L1.

Comment: This is another question based on the false premise that an optimisation is mandatory, so there must be a justification if it isn't implemented.  The standard does not *require* such an optimisation, so an implementation is permitted to not provide it.   And any implementations which do provide it may make it optional (e.g. disabled by default, optionally activated via optimisation settings) and/or subject to analysis (e.g.  only performed if relevant metrics are calculated [which they may not be] and show a benefit).